# What information is neccessary to restore an image from a scaled down version?

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I have an image and a version that is scaled down to exactly half the width and height. The Lanczos filter (with a = 3) has been used to scale the image. Color spaces can be ignored, all colors are in a linear space.

Since the small image contains one pixel for each 2x2 pixel block of the original I'm thinking it should be possible to restore the original image from the small one with just 3 additional color values per 2x2 pixel block. However, I do not know how to calculate those 3 color values.

The original image has four times as much information as the scaled version. Using the original image I want to calculate the 3/4 of information that is missing in the scaled version such that I can use the scaled version and the calculated missing information to reconstruct the original image.

Consider the following use-case: Over a network you send the scaled image to a user as a thumbnail. Now the user wants to see the image at full size. How can we avoid repeating information that is already in the thumbnail? As far as I can tell progressive image compression algorithms do not manage to do this with more complex filtering.

For the box filter the problem is trivial. But since the kernels of the Lanczos filter overlap each other I do not know how to solve it. Given that this is just a linear system of equations I believe it is solvable. Additionally I would rather avoid deconvolution in frequency space.

How can I calculate the information that is missing in the down-scaled version and use it to restore the original image?

Comment: It's not true at all that "For the box filter the problem is trivial." It's impossible to re-create an arbitrary original image from a downsampled version, regardless of the sampling filter. You'll have to do a better job of explaining the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: In the downscaled image you have 1/4th the information of the original image. Unless you saved elsewhere the 3/4 information that is not in the downscaled image, you cannot recover it. Imagine if this were possible. You could repeat the downscaling operation an infinite number of times, and store an arbitrary image using a single pixel, without loss of information!

Comment: Indeed, it is impossible without the 3/4 of information that is lost, @Gene. I'm sorry this wasn't clear in my question: I'm looking for a way to calculate those 3/4 of information given the original image.